# SaveFileDialog doesn't show any possible extensions despite using Filter option

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating right now an application in C# which saves data to the file upon clicking a button. The name and locations of the file is defined by the user, and i want the program to automatically add .txt extension to the name, as well as show only 1 possible extensions in "save files as" combobox. I have this code:

```
SaveFileDialog Dialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
Dialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
Dialog1.Filter = "Pliki tekstowe | *.txt";
Dialog1.AddExtension = true;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Dialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.Stream fileStream = Dialog1.OpenFile();
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileStream);
        sw.WriteLine("Writing some text in the file.");
        sw.WriteLine("Some other line.");
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

But whenever i click the button, i have no options to choose from in the combobox, as well as the .txt extensions are not added to the file name in case the extensions is not specified by the user himself. I know i can somehow bypass that by checking if the user gave the proper extensions, and in case he didn't add ".txt" to the name but i really wanted to know, why that piecei of code doesn't function. Any help?

Comment: The only thing that jumps out are the spaces around the pipe separators (|). If you remove these, does that resolve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the space. Just change it to this:

```
Dialog1.Filter = "Pliki tekstowe|*.txt";
```

and you should be in business.

Otherwise it's trying to match files of the pattern  `*.txt` (subtly compared to `*.txt`) - which you probably don't have.

Comment: I replaced that line with the code suggested by below answer (from msdn):
   Dialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
but id didnt help. I still have blank combobox and no extension added

Comment: If I use the filter written as above I am able to see only text (.txt) files from my file system. Are you sure you typed it exactly as I have?

Comment: It turnes out i made two mistakes - the one you mentioned and also I put SaveFileDialog on my form in designer and named her Dialog1, which somehow was the reason for all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the following example and see the difference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

you should try firstly to add this to your filter:

```
"txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
```

for completeness you should add the (*.txt) string in your filter for descriptive reasons (thanks for clarifying Yuck). Try it - see what happens :)
remember it is sensitive in terms of the string. so try not to put things like a space between the file extensions

Comment: Correct solution, wrong reason. The parenthesis around the extension wildcard has nothing to do with its effect. In fact, the first part of each pair is descriptive only.

Comment: seems like the editor modified the original text I copied in here! @Yuck - agreed with you. I personally like to show it all, if that makes sense (the descriptive)

Answer (score 0):

I had  a similar issue where the save dialog box on firefox and safari doesn't detect the file extension even though I had Content-Type header set to "application/pdf". The issue turned out to be spaces in the name of the file. I replaced the file name with '-' (hyphens) and that fixed it.